# Loop through iterations and save multiple select options from custom meta box

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I'm attempting to save multiple options selected from a multi-select menu as Wordpress meta box. The possible options are simple (integers 1 through 6), but I'm not sure how to increase the counter ($i++) and save all results that are selected by the user. When a user updates the edit page, the select menu only displays the last selected option and not both or all options selected.

```
<select name="show_sched[<?php echo $c; ?>][frequency]" multiple="multiple" size="4">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"<?php if($track['frequency'] == $i) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Set name to `show_sched[<?php echo $c; ?>][frequency][]` and check `_POST[<?php echo $c; ?>][frequency]`

Comment: Thx @u_mulder Setting the name to include the third set of square brackets (array?), I'm there. Check '_POST', though. Check it where?

Comment: In your script that saves values. D'you have it?

Comment: @u_mulder, yes. If I understand the code correctly, it's not the actual script at top (that adds the additional rows of fields), but the save function below that? Here's the remaining code: http://paste.scratchbook.ch/view/faca86bd

Comment: Would I add another if statement in between those within myplaylist_save_showpostdata starting at line 196 and check `_POST[<?php echo $c; ?>][frequency]` there? http://paste.scratchbook.ch/view/a3227b22